# Parallel code is taking longer time than sequential code using Parallel computing toolbox in MATLAB. Why?

Tags: performance, matlab, parallel-processing, multicore

I am working with MATLAB. I am just new with parallel computing toolbox in MATLAB. I have core i3 processor, MATLAB R2011a, 2 GB of RAM, 320 Hard disk.

To calculate speed up, I just wrote following code and found that parallel code is taking longer time than a sequential code.

1st code is taking  **0.039763 seconds**

2nd code is taking  **0.379056 seconds**.

---

1st code:

```
tic
MM = magic(5);
MN = magic(5);
ML = magic(5);
MP = magic(5);
MK = magic(5);
MM
MN
ML
MP
MK
toc
```

2nd Code:

```
matlabpool open local 4

tic
spmd  % Uses all 3 workers
    MM = magic(5); % MM is a variable on each lab
end
MM{1}
MM{2}
MM{3}
MM{4}
toc
matlabpool close
```

I want to learn parallel computing toolbox.

Comment: Try it with a bigger problem. Perhaps the overhead of parallelization is more costly than the speedup for a problem of such a small scale?

Comment: Additionally, try to use different operations for workers. Matlab can speedup calculations for several identical sequential operations.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Dan in the comments, the problem is clearly too small for parallelization to be beneficial. Increasing for example the size of the `magic` matrices you create from 5 to 5000, already shows a clear improvement. That is, with the larger size the overhead of parallelization becomes (almost) negligible compared to the computation time for one matrix.

Comment: Thanks, But i have tried this to create 4000000 matrices but it is not giving desired result. Please suggest me suitable code.